# create a smooth surface using x,y,z data gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file which contains x,y,z data. Actually, the data is:

x = latitude
y = longitude
z= Depth

I want to create a smooth surface but I have no idea how to do it. Could anybody give me some hints to do it?

**UPDATE**

So, the data looks like the next lines:

```
-62.323 19.242  58.7
-62.213 10.886  120.2
-62.329 10.797  71.9
-62.383 10.690  1.3
-60.121 11.567  24.5
-60.481 12.894  3
-62.118 10.944  69.1
-60.825 15.803  25.5
-61.792 16.227  148.3
-63.288 10.817  28.4
-59.092 14.344  3
-61.836 11.217  67.7
-61.346 14.799  191.2
-61.152 15.427  126.6
-60.959 16.035  55.8
-61.364 15.283  151.6
-62.071 11.222  109.5
-62.420 10.672  72.1
-60.267 14.009  13.1
-60.604 14.033  65.4
-60.623 10.307  42.4
-62.272 17.936  75
-60.464 13.908  40.9
-60.722 14.701  181.5
-62.125 10.911  47.1
-62.530 10.544  5.2
-60.170 12.752  71.5
-60.929 14.635  87.9
-62.279 10.936  74.3
-62.267 10.767  75.8
-60.708 10.440  36.2
-62.440 10.463  2.6
-62.477 10.217  3
-62.399 10.651  58.7
```

There are more points. The idea is to create the plane or surface along the depth (the third column).

Comment: What do you have so far? And is the data file formatted like that every line? Can you show an example? Other information, such as the range of the data, is also helpful

Answer (score 22):

Basically, you plot surfaces with the  `splot` command. `data_file` contains your example data points.

```
gnuplot> splot 'data_file'
```

[image]

As you want a smooth surface, you have to specify that you want gnuplot to interpolate the data. Here is an example, see http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/dgrid3d.html for some others.

```
gnuplot> set hidden3d
gnuplot> set dgrid3d 50,50 qnorm 2
gnuplot> splot 'data_file' with lines
```

[image]

There are a lot of parameters you can adjust, e.g. what interpolation function is used. As it is very hard to cover all here in a general answer, I want to recommend to start with the documentation about `splot` and `set dgrid3d`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with pm3d? Instead of having a line contour, is it possible to produce a smooth surface contour with interpolation?

Comment: @V-Red: Yes, that's possible straight forward... have you tried it? Regarding interpolation please read the link provided in the answer.

Comment: Yes, it works very nicely when I replace <set hidden3d> with <set pm3d interpolate 1,1> and <splot ' ' with lines> with <splot ' ' with pm3d>